# Following code runs without any error but record is not inserted into the table

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm, pymysql

```
import pymysql


db_host = "localhost"
db_name = "mydatabse"
table_name = "Student"
db_user = "root"
db_pass = "745269"

query_insert = "INSERT INTO " + table_name + " (stu_id, stu_name) VALUES (%s, %s) "


class Student:
    id = 0
    name = ""

    def __init__(self, sid, name):
        self.id = sid
        self.name = name


def insert_record(rec):
    #print((rec.id, rec.name))
    con = pymysql.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, password=db_pass, database=db_name)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query_insert, (rec.id, rec.name))
    #$cur.execute("INSERT INTO Student VALUES (%s, %s)", (3, 'Qwerty'))


r1 = Student(3, "Qwerty")
insert_record(r1)
```

I am trying to insert new rows to database using pymysql module. I am planning to define all queries globally like INSERT one. I guess I am missing some formatting of the queries but have not been able to point it so far. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html, "connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save your changes."

Which would result in:

```
import pymysql


db_host = "localhost"
db_name = "mydatabse"
table_name = "Student"
db_user = "root"
db_pass = "745269"

query_insert = "INSERT INTO " + table_name + " (stu_id, stu_name) VALUES (%s, %s) "


class Student:
    id = 0
    name = ""

    def __init__(self, sid, name):
        self.id = sid
        self.name = name


def insert_record(rec):
    #print((rec.id, rec.name))
    con = pymysql.connect(host=db_host, user=db_user, password=db_pass, database=db_name)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query_insert, (rec.id, rec.name))
    #$cur.execute("INSERT INTO Student VALUES (%s, %s)", (3, 'Qwerty'))
    con.commit()  # Added this commit call


r1 = Student(3, "Qwerty")
insert_record(r1)
```